# wordpress - trying to use count() inside $wpdb->get_results but returns empty result

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get how many rows contains the same product id in this table.  I mean how many times a product is repeated in this table
for example product id = 1000 and number of instances  is 3.
This is my code :

```php
$prod_id_query = "SELECT prod_id , COUNT(prod_id)    AS repeat_num  FROM {$wpdb->wlfmc_items} GROUP BY prod_id  ";
$prods_ids = $wpdb->get_results($prod_id_query);      
print_r($prods_ids);
```

but the result is empty.  It returns empty array.

Comment: What is the value of `$wpdb->wlfmc_items`? Have you tried dumping the `$prod_id_query` string and running it manually on your DB? You could also check `$wpdb->last_error` to see if your query failed

Comment: $wpdb->wlfmc_items this shows the name of the table and it's working fine
i tried the code without COUNT(prod_id)    AS repeat_num  and it's working fine .

$wpdb->last_error >> shows nothing

Answer (score 0):

thanks for everyone tried to help i found that the problem was with (AS repeat_num  FROM)
the corrrection is the semicolon >> ( AS 'repeat_num'  FROM )

iam using mariaDB

now it's working thanks